# Limiting a textile pattern to Pantone colours

Tags: adobe-photoshop, pantone

When working in Photoshop to design a textile pattern using Pantone C colours, how do I ensure that the colour palate is limited to Pantone even after blending colours to achieve gradients and watercolour effects?

I'm starting with this:[image]

In an attempt to produce something like this - or as near as possible:

[image]

Comment: In Photoshop this can only be achieved by working directly in *channels*. You can't use Pantone colors in layers with masks and blend modes and all that.

Comment: Thanks! Would I be able to specify opacity in different channels to help create a blended effect?

Comment: No, you can't specify opacity for a channel. You need to draw things with the right "opacity" to begin with. Actually, in channels there is no opacity. They are just grayscale images specifying how much of each ink you want for each pixel. The channels are always overprinted. If you don't want colors to mix you have to manually make holes in the other channels. (Hard to explain here in comments and your question is very broad, so I'm not up to writing a proper answer right now. Could you post a screenshot showing your artwork and your layers to make it easier to find a fitting method?)

Comment: Thanks, Wolff. See above. I'd like to know if you can achieve that effect by drawing things with the right "opacity" to begin with, as you say...?

Comment: How many Pantone colors can you use? Only one? Then this wouldn't be possible. But with two it might be possible. The thing is that the hue of your light colors isn't the same as the hue of your dark colors. If you just use a dark blue like the darkest in your image it wouldn't get so vibrant in the light tints.

Comment: For some reason, my client hasn't specified a number of colours, which I imagine means I could use however many are necessary to create the look she wants...How would you go about it in this case? Thanks!

Comment: Note that on **channels** tint can often equal opacity. e.g. 100% black on the *channel* means 100% color, 50% grey on the *channel* means a 50% tint of the color. One really doesn't *want* to use transparency with spot colors. Results are unpredictable and can't be achieved with straight spots... on press... there's no such thing as opacity. When opacity is used in CMYK/RGB the colors are *flattened* resulting in *new* CMYK/RGB colors, not transparent colors. ---- And.. anything more than 3 spot colors is often not cost effective. Sometimes 4 spots is okay, but I'd question anything more.

Comment: [This question](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/43315/how-to-save-a-photoshop-image-for-indesign-and-preserve-the-pantones/43316#43316) *may* be helpful. Unfortunately, it's a bit old and has suffered from some link rot. -- [This](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/121304/color-separation-for-offset-printing-in-photoshop) may also be helpful.